# Microsoft SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

I've been asked to design and develop a corporate website.
Design is done. Initial plans were to use LAMP. Now the client just dropped a bomb on us saying that:

> (due to strict security policies of
>   the final client) we are to
>   develop/deploy this website with
>   SharePoint

I have no real idea of what is SharePoint, and what are the implications of this request.

- Can you briefly explain what is
  SharePoint?
- Do you need a license to deploy a
  SharePoint website?
- What do you need to develop for it?
  (license, tools)
- Does it need to run on a IIS server?
- What language will/could be used?

I have googled a bit before posting, but I have not managed to get a clear idea of what SharePoint is and how it works. Also, atm I'm rushing to accommodate for this hiccup on the project but I'm pretty much blindfolded until I understand what I just got into.

Comment: I feel this is appropriate: http://i.imgur.com/ReGfT.gif

Comment: @Brandon Moretz: It's funny in a sad way, it hurts.

Comment: I hear you, I don't konw  much about LMaP ;) I can only imagine whats going on behind this project but on he surface it sounds like a huge last minute U turn - maybe @Michael has the best advice in his comment below?

Comment: Yes and no. We are not going to develop the project but I still have to manage it, unfortunately. Terrible U turn, just disjointed my neck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SharePoint is both an application platform (SharePoint Foundation) as well as an implementation on top of that platform (SharePoint Server/Enterprise) designed for common office collaboration scenarios. It is one of Microsoft's signature enterprise platforms, and as such builds entirely, and exclusively, on their tech. (And also drives a lot of their revenues.) So:

- You do need a license to deploy a SharePoint website, and there are lots of options depending on the size of the deployment.
- You develop for SharePoint using Visual Studio. It's possible to do in other tools, but that's Microsoft's preferred solution. If your project is very simple, there's a free tool called SharePoint Designer, but if a client is hiring you for this project, it's probably beyond the scope of that tool.
- It runs only on IIS.
- You create SharePoint apps in ASP.net

In short, this would be a **huge** transition from a traditional LAMP development/deployment process, especially if you're an emacs or vi person who builds in PHP or Python by preference. If your questions are this fundamental about SharePoint, then this change of platforms isn't a hiccup, it may be time to farm this project out or politely decline.

Comment: 'hiccup', was being ironic...

Comment: Small Nitpick: SharePoint Foundation is a full implementation and does not require licensing other than the Windows/SQL Server it runs on. SharePoint Standard/Enterprise extend Foundation with other functionality. Agree with the last sentence: This is so far away from LAMP, you should take the project back to the drawing board or walk away from it.

Comment: @Michael - he mentions corporate **website** so that indicates that it will be available externally - in this case an external connector license is required even if using Foundation.

Comment: @Ryan does that apply even when running on Windows 2008 Web? The licensing around that one are weird as 2008 Web already includes an External Connector and only needs licenses for internal users, but I don't know if SP Foundation requires the Internet Connector even here.

Comment: AFAIK it does as the external connector license is for Windows not SP. But you know I will say there are only 3 people in the world who really understand this lot. One is dead, one is mad and the other has forgotten ;)

Answer (score 4):

Can you briefly explain what is Sharepoint?

Microsoft's all-in-one powerhouse tool that's been gaining a lot of traction lately.  Used heavily (and often inappropriately) by lots of corporations for internal document management, portal-type communities, and workflow solutions.

Do you need a license to deploy a Sharepoint website?

SharePoint Foundation is free.  SharePoint Server is not.  SharePoint Server comes with additional tools that your client may or may not need.

What do you need to develop for it? (license, tools)

The only real way to develop for SharePoint is Visual Studio 2010.  2010 specifically because they added a ton of new SharePoint-specific features to it (MS is pushing SharePoint *really* hard.)

Does it need to run on a IIS server?

Yes.

What language will/could be used?

Any .NET language, I believe.  I've only done it in C#.

In summary: you need to take a big, long step back and discuss this with the client.  For one, SharePoint has a massive API that's going to take a while to learn, especially if you're working with LAMP developers.  For two, SharePoint is **the** most in-demand skill in enterprise software development right now.  If you need to hire SharePoint developers; take the average salary of a software dev in your area, and double it, because that's how much a decent SharePoint developer will cost.

This is to say nothing of the non-development side of things, such as server administration, information architecture, and content management.

Answer (score 1):

You say "corporate **website**" so this indicates that it will be visible to people external to the organisation (i.e. publicly accessible on the web).

In this case you do need to purchase an External Connector license, even if using the ['free' SharePoint 2010 Foundation](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2010/11/how-much-does-sharepoint-cost/).